# how to pass a pointer to struct to another function in C, in calling function if I have access to only pointer variable

Tags: c

I have a function

```
void get_alloc_single_struct(void **arr)
{
    *arr=malloc(sizeof(**arr));
}
```

I like to know how to call this above function from main for example

I am doing it like this

```
 struct ads *data1=NULL;
 get_alloc_single_struct(&(data1));
```

But But I am getting a warning and "note:..."

```
:29: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘get_alloc_single_struct’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   24 |     get_alloc_single_struct(&(data1));
      |                             ^~~~~~~~
      |                             |
      |                             struct ads **
data.c:14:37: note: expected ‘void **’ but argument is of type ‘struct ads **’
   14 | void get_alloc_single_struct(void **arr)
```

when compiled with -Wall -Wextra

What I am doing wrong

Comment: `sizeof(**arr)` is unknown since you declare it `void`

Comment: `void **` and `struct ads **` are incompatible. `void *` is compatible with every other pointer type, but not `void **`.

Comment: what exactly `get_alloc_single_struct()` is supposed to do? Allocate what?

Comment: This has been asked many times before. I can't bother finding a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of types ("double void" i.e. `void **`) is a bit of a red flag here. If you want to wrap `malloc()`, the best idea is to keep the same interface.

You cannot *both* make the interface use `void *` like that, *and* have it compute the required size using `sizeof`, since you explicitly drop the type information when you go `void`.

So, if you want to drop the size from the call you have to encode it in the function itself, i.e. specialize it:

```
struct ads * get_alloc_ads(void)
{
  return malloc(sizeof (struct ads));
}
```

or be a 100% wrap and pass in the size:

```
void * get_alloc(size_t bytes)
{
  return malloc(bytes);
}
```

of course in the latter case you could also add logging, exit-on-failure, or other features specific to your application otherwise the wrapping becomes pointless.

Answer (score 1):

The function `get_alloc_single_struct` shall **not** have a parameter of type `void **`. The parameter must be `struct ads **`. So simply do:

```
void get_alloc_single_struct(void **arr) --> void get_alloc_single_struct(struct ads **arr)
```

The reason is `sizeof`...

With a `void **` parameter, you end up doing `sizeof(void)` which is **not** what you want. You want `sizeof(struct ads)` so the parameter must be `struct ads **`.

That said... It doesn't make much sense to write the function like that. Passing a pointer to an actual object is not needed when all you want is to know the sizeof of an object type.

Comment: Or how about the way I did in answer. Can u please check. it does not print any thing when program compiled with `-Wall -Wextra - Werror`

Answer (score -1):

thanks for the answers I think I should do it like this

```
struct ads{
    int id;
    char *title;
    char *name;
};

void* get_alloc_single(size_t bytes)
{
    return malloc(bytes);
}

int main()
{
    struct ads *data1=get_alloc_single(sizeof(struct ads));
    data1->title=get_alloc_single(10);

    strcpy(data1->title, "fawad khan")
    data1->id=102;

    printf("%s %d\n",data1->title,data1->id);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: can u please explain why

Comment: thanks I have updated the code. Now using strcpy plus without cast

Comment: What's the point of having `get_alloc_single` as straight wrapper for `malloc`?

Comment: That function is just useless bloat making the code harder to read. Don't re-invent the C language to replace it with some private, secret language...